# Hover Boots: Ocarina of Time

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

Are the hover boots used for anything in OOT? because I can't find a use for them and I've beaten the game, they just make me slide around a lot and not be able to jump. Is there a purpose for them?

Comment: You need them to finish the Shadow Temple, for one.

Comment: IIRC, some spots in Ganon's Castle also require it (most notably, the shadow room). How did you beat the game without using them...?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [Zeldapedia](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Hover_Boots):

> Their main purpose is to **allow Link to walk on water or thin air for a few seconds** and thereby cross otherwise impassable pitfalls. This useful, and sometimes necessary ability, is offset by the fact that the boots maintain rather poor traction while on solid ground. […]
>
> Since the Hover Boots only work a brief moment, their practical use is rather limited. However, **they feature several other**, less obvious, **benefits** that are apparent from time to time, the most notable of **which is the fact that Link**, while hovering, **can easily change direction in mid-air**, an ability that is much more limited while simply jumping. The boots also **reduce Link's weight**, **which keeps him from sinking in quicksand, weight-sensitive platforms** and, in rare cases, **allows him to foil certain pressure-sensitive traps.**

(bold emphasis mine)

Comment: You can also use them to get several heart pieces which would otherwise require a grown magic bean (the ones on top of Dodongo cavern and near the Zora falls come to mind)

Comment: Their practical use is a lot greater in Master Quest. The entirety of the Shadow Temple is basically built around them.